# Perform NSGA 2 without variables

Tags: optimization

I have a data set with two columns. The variable names are cost 1 and cost 2. I want to minimize both cost 1 and cost 2 using the Pareto optimization method. So, while implementing NSGA II I have two objective functions i.e. cost 1 values and cost 2 values but I don't have any variables in it since my data set already contains the cost values which are calculated by using the variable values (see the data set below). So, what I want is find the pair of cost values [cost 1,cost 2] which lie in the Pareto front. Can I perform NSGA II for this scenario?

data = np.array([[97, 23],
[55, 77],
[34, 76],
[80, 60],
[99,  4],
[81,  5],
[ 5, 81],
[30, 79],
[15, 80],
[70, 65],
[90, 40],
[40, 30],
[30, 40],
[20, 60],
[60, 50],
[20, 20],
[30,  1],
[60, 40],
[70, 25],
[44, 62],
[55, 55],
[55, 10],
[15, 45],
[83, 22],
[76, 46],
[56, 32],
[45, 55],
[10, 70],
[10, 30],
[79, 50]])

Comment: NSGA : please explain this acronym...

Comment: nondominated sorting genetic algorithm II (NSGA-II)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, since you do not have integer/float 'decision variables', I do not see the point of using NSGA II. Your case is much simpler. From the question, I gather that you have all the discrete 'options' as given and their attributed costs with respect to two objectives. In this case, in fact, by implementing a rather simple function you can determine whether an option is 'Pareto dominated' by another option, and then use this function to find the non-dominated ones. The non-dominated options will be the Pareto frontier or the Pareto optimal options. For gaining a better insight you can visualize these points on a 2D plot, noting that each of them represents an option, and then you will see that the ones in whose lower-left quadrant there does not exist any other point are the Pareto (cost-minimal) optimal solutions. A solution/option is said to be Pareto-dominated by another if the other is better (less costly in this case) w.r.t. all objectives.